# ATMEGA 2560 => MCP4725 => FC-33 => Electronic Pressure Regulator

Tags: microcontroller, 4-20ma

I am purchasing a regulator that accepts a 4-20mA control. I am hoping to interface this to an ATMEGA2560 microcontroller.

I am looking at using a MCP4725 DAC driven by the I2C bus of the microcontroller to provide a 0-5v output signal with a resolution of .0012 V. (https://www.adafruit.com/product/935)

Output of the DAC would go to V+ and COM input of the following FC-33.

To go from that output to the 4-20mA output I desire, and to gain isolation between devices I am hoping to use an FC-33 signal conditioner to read the 0-5v output and convert to the 4-20mA output. This should be a supported configuration through the DIP switches. (https://cdn.automationdirect.com/static/manuals/scdatasheet/fc_33.pdf)

The current output of the FC-33 will feed the input signal for this regulator. https://www.alliedelec.com/product/smc-corporation/itv2030-01n2l4/70070679/

Is there anything else I would need to make this work? Is this overkill?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Not sure how much you want to spend, but there are current loop drivers for that like XTR300, industrial electronics is expensive, yeah. Further, industrial analog IOs do prefer galvanic isolation, even more expensive.  I would definitely buy on of these: r https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33052139206.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.2726491bY6F62v&algo_pvid=b94235f9-8f2f-4f0d-a40e-971df848f3a4&algo_expid=b94235f9-8f2f-4f0d-a40e-971df848f3a4-6&btsid=0be3743615828346469914054eb5b1&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: Do you need to use the 4 - 20 mA type?  That same regulator comes in a 0 - 5 V or 0 - 10 V type.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the FC-33 if you choose a DAC that has a current source output.

There are many 4 - 20 mA output DACs on the market that can interface directly with a microcontroller such as your ATMEGA2560.

The [AD421](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/data-acquisition-adcs-dacs-special-purpose/768?k=ad421) is one example.

That regulator is also available in a 0 - 5 V input type.

Comment: Well the nice thing about the MCP4725 is the fact that there are breakout boards readily available using that chip. When I say the 2560, I'm using the Arduino version of that and so it should interface nicely with the breakout board I am using and be very simple for me. 

I agree the AD421 would be more direct but I cannot find a breakout board for this and at least for short term it would be quicker for me to use the FC-33 as the intermediary. Do you see this being a problem?

Comment: @BeauGott No, I think you have a viable solution.  I was mostly responding to your question about overkill.  Now that I am aware of your preference for pre-built boards, this makes good sense.  Current drive can have some advantages over voltage drive in noisy environments anyway.